# Wipe NSData contents in Swift

Tags: objective-c, security, memory, swift, nsdata

I have an NSData object that will contain sensitive data.  When the operation is complete, I would like to wipe the memory to avoid any potential security issues.  In Objective-C, this is easy.  I can just call...

```
memset([mySensitiveData bytes], 0, [mySensitiveData length]);
```

In Swift, however, it is not as straightforward.  I tried the equivalent...

```
memset(mySensitiveData.bytes, 0, mySensitiveData.length)
```

...however, I get a compiler error saying...

```
'UnsafePointer<Void>' is not convertible to 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>'
```

Any idea how to get around this and wipe the memory safely in Swift?  Thanks!!

Comment: Note that `memset()` does not guarantee that the data is actually overwritten. The compiler is free to optimize this out in various situations. It is in fact extremely difficult to be certain that memory is overwritten. Swift makes even fewer promises about this than C and C++. https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/MSC06-CPP.+Be+aware+of+compiler+optimization+when+dealing+with+sensitive+data

Comment: @RobNapier You said: `Swift makes even fewer promises about this than C and C++.`. Can you please explain why or give a proof link?

Comment: C and C++ have specific specs that guarantee certain memory behaviors (C99 and C++11 for instance). Swift has no such spec that guarantees what a conforming compiler will do with `resetBytesInRange:`. Promises of behavior are made explicitly, not implicitly. Who can point to a document that details what Swift must do in this case to be conforming? All we have is the Swift Programming Language guide, which does not cover this kind of case.

Comment: Something akin to `volatile` is required even to try to implement an overwrite. If you just write to a memory location you never read later, compilers in most languages are free to ignore your write. Swift doesn't have anything like `volatile` today. We can try to guess what the implementation of `resetBytesInRange:` probably is, and try to rely on that, but `NSData` is built on top of `dispatch_data`, which has numerous surprising optimizations (such as copy-on-write and other sharing techniques) that can interfere with the goal here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSData` is immutable that's why it uses `UnsafePointer<Void>` for bytes pointer.

You should use [`NSMutableData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/index.html) for this and then just call: `resetBytesInRange(NSMakeRange(0, mySensitiveData.length))`.  This method will replace contents with zeroes as `memset` does.